# Python: Extracting Variable Names from a List of Strings

Tags: python, list, attributes, names

I have three dataframes:

```
butterflies
monkeys
tigers
```

The dataframes are stored in a list called "creatures", which corresponds with a list of strings called "family":

```
creatures = [butterflies, monkeys, tigers]
family = ["insects", "hominids", "cats"]
```

I created a helper function for assigning a 'category' attribute to the dataframes in the creature list:

```
# Helper Function for Assigning Categories
def assign_family(creatures, family):
    
    assigned_frames = []
    for creature, category in zip(creatures, family):
        creature.category = category
        assigned_frames.append(creature.category)
        
    return assigned_frames
```

It works!

If I run the function, as follows, and type "butterflies.category":

```
categories = assign_family(creatures, family)
butterflies.category
```

I get:

```
"insects"
```

However, the small problem is that when I print the variable "categories", as follows, I get:

```
print(categories)
["insects", "hominids", "cats"]
```

For ease of reference, I would like the "print(categories)" command to return the names of the categories as follows:

```
print(categories)
[butterflies.category, monkeys.category, tigers.category]
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is inside `butterflies.group` ? You're appending `creature.category` in your loop and this is whats in your list later on!

Comment: Typographical error. Corrected now.